# Microsoft Graph subscription expirationDateTime incorrect

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Having issues creating a subscription, specifically setting the `expirationDateTime` field in the beta API.

According to the docs maximum expiration time is '4320 minutes (3 days)' on the contacts resource.

When I make the request, I receive an error message of `Subscription expiration can only be 4230 minutes in the future`. Obviously this conflicts with their documentation. Now, if I adjust the `expirationDateTime` attribute I am sending to make a subscription request from 4320 minutes to 4230 minutes, it works as expected.

Is this a documentation issue or a mistype in their API source?

Resources:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/subscription

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription

Comment: Does it work with 4319 minutes?  I'm just wondering if it is a < vs <= issue.

Comment: I haven't tried. It seems that you can go up to ~4310 minutes. Initially, I set three days then kept subtracting batches of minutes until it was successful (3 days - 10 minutes went through). In the end, I decided to just add 4230 to the current time and called it a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue in the documentation. It is being updated now. The maximum lifetime is 4230 minutes.