Create webook to get notified, user create and update in azure portal
I want to create a webhook to get notified when a user is created or updated on the Azure active directory. My goal is to trigger a function app using the webhook.
Is there a separate Graph API to get those details?


Create a subscription in Graph API which will monitor users for creation and updating.
Follow the below steps to trigger the function when new user is created or updated.
Create a App Registration

Create a new app registration
Assign permission in Api Users.ReadWrite.All for Delegate and Application.



Give Admin consent

Create a Function App and deploy a HTTP trigger function
I have created a .NET 8 Http Trigger function.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp13
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Webhook triggered.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            if (req.Query.ContainsKey("validationToken"))
            {
                string validationToken = req.Query["validationToken"];
                _logger.LogInformation($"Validation token received: {validationToken}");
                return new ContentResult()
                {
                    Content = validationToken,
                    ContentType = "text/plain",
                    StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK
                };
            }

            var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WebhookNotification>(requestBody);

            _logger.LogInformation($"Notification received: {data.value}");

            string expectedClientState = "state_secret";
            if (data?.value[0]?.clientState != expectedClientState)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Client state mismatch.");
                return new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
            
            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
    public class WebhookNotification
    {
        public List<UserEventData> value { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserEventData
    {
        public string clientState { get; set; }

    }
}


Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(option => option.Rules.Clear());
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Deploy it to function and get the URL.
Create Subscription in Graph API
I am using Postman here to create subscription.

Generate Access token using the created App registration and get the token value.
To create subscription use POST method using URL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions with raw body in json data

{
    "changeType": "created,updated",
    "notificationUrl": "https://graphfunc6june.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1",  #your function http trigger url
    "resource": "/users",
    "expirationDateTime": "2024-06-08T05:00:00Z",
    "clientState": "state_secret"
}


Use token value in the Authorization section to authorize
Send request which will create subscription using the Azure function Url.



Now when ever new user is created or existing user is updated it will trigger the HTTP trigger.

OUTPUT:



Im tring to create the subscription from postman
Subscription expiration can only be 4230 minutes in the future.
Will it be only valid for 4230 minutes(3 days) cannot we extend the expiration

When I try this approach, I tried with nodejs application. For notificationUrl validation i need to send an specific response at the first time to create the subscription.
notificationUrl: 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/webhook'
app.post('/webhook', async (req, res) => {     res.status(200).send(req.query.validationToken); });

@ Dileepa Mabulage can you share your Node js full code

you can change the expiration based on your requirement. during subscription creation you can set the expirtaion date in request body

If I change the expiration date more than 3 days {   "error": {     "code": "ExtensionError",     "message": "Subscription expiration can only be 4230 minutes in the future.",     "innerError": {       "request-id": "a0744d2b-5739-4904-9cac-33762e058d32",       "date": "2018-04-20T09:02:41"     }   } }
this error throws

@DileepaMabulage I tried to extend my expiration date to 15th june and it worked perfectly fine for me image. I would suggest to cross check if you have any policy in your subscription which does not allow to create subscriotion longer than 3 days. or any other policy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065117/microsoft-graph-subscription-expirationdatetime-incorrect can you check the answer for this, There is no specific policy set for expiration in the Azure AD

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
